# Trying to compile with make on Windows gives error 127

Tags: windows, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

this is the very first time that I try to compile anything in Windows and it already gives me the creeps (not because of Windows that is).
I downloaded a dictionary from here:

https://www.j3e.de/ispell/igerman98/dict/igerman98-20161207.tar.bz2

When I extract the folder then there is a Makefile, so I think that I have to compile the progrmam first. I tried that with two methods: first Cygwin, second MinGW. Both programs are in my PATH.

I use the terminal of both programs to navigate to D:/igerman98 and there I enter

```
make
```

The first message I get is:

```
$ make
A default make target doesn't exist. You might want to use one of those:
  make hunspell/de_DE.dic hunspell/de_DE.aff (or de_AT or de_CH)
  make myspell/de_DE.dic myspell/de_DE.aff (or de_AT or de_CH)
  make ispell/de_DE.aff ispell/de_DE.hash (or de_AT, de_CH ...)
  make aspell/de_DE.rws (or de_AT, de_CH ...)
  make ligature/rmligs
  make isowordlist-de_DE (or de_AT, de_CH ...)
Did I forget an important one ?-)
```

So I enter again the following:

```
make hunspell/de_DE.dic hunspell/de_DE.aff
```

But then I get the following error:

```
$ make hunspell/de_DE.dic hunspell/de_DE.aff
test -e all.words.placebo.tmp || echo a > all.words.placebo.tmp
buildhash all.words.placebo.tmp ispell/de_DE_null.aff ispell/de_DE_null.hash
make: buildhash: Command not found
make: *** [ispell/de_DE_null.hash] Error 127
```

What am I doing wrong here? I just want de_DE.dic and de_DE.aff files to be created so I can use them with the spelling module in Textadept...

Comment: This is not a compilation error; your SO tags are not right.  Make is trying to run the program `buildhash`, but that program doesn't exist on your system so it fails.  I'm not familiar with the package you're trying to build so I don't know whether that program is supposed to come with it, or you need to install it yourself first, or what.  But, the issue is with the package you're trying to build not make, the compiler, or windows.  You should ask for help on a list or forum dedicated to that package (or add SO tags related to that package).

Comment: thanks for your reply and your suggestion. i will try to contact the devs.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, the program `buildhash` comes with the ispell-package. Under Windows, you can use: [ISPELL for Windwos](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~dvanness/ispell.htm)